# Не работает сервис ubuntu при загрузке телеграм бота на сервер systemctl

Tags: python, ubuntu, telegram, aiogram, putty

Нужно реализовать постоянный онлайн телеграм бота. Купил сервер, пытаюсь написать для него сервис, но выдает ошибку. Что может быть не так?

Код сервиса:

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/root/wiedzminbot/
User= root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 bot.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

Ошибка при вводе команды "systemctl enable olgierd":

```
root@olgierd:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl enable olgierd
Failed to enable unit: File olgierd.service: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Можно чуть подробнее куда и как вы помещали сам сервис.

Comment: Уже все получилось. Немного переписал код. Позже выложу ответом. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Получилось исправить самостоятельно!

Код:

```
[Unit]
Description=Telegram bot for t.me/wiedzminChat
After=syslog.target
After=netwotck.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/root/wiedzminbot/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /root/wiedzminbot/bot.py
RestartSec=60
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```